# How to export a org file to R, commenting everything except R code?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I want to convert an org file to an R file by commenting all the lines except those with R code, using the export functionality if possible. I have come across org-export-generic.el (http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html) that apparently would do what I want, but it seems outdated.

Here's an example org-mode file:

```
* Install packages

You can install a package using the =install.packages= function:

#+BEGIN_SRC R
install.packages("data.table")
#+END_SRC

then you need to load the package:

#+BEGIN_SRC R
library(data.table)
#+END_SRC
```

If I use the tangle functionality I get the following R file:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
```

While my goal is to get the following R file:

```
## * Install packages

## You can install a package using the =install.packages= function:

install.packages("data.table")

## then you need to load the package:

library(data.table)
```

Comment: Might get a more helpful response at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/. Perhaps migrate the question there. Also, as an org user this seems to me more of a how do I do something in org rather than a recommendation for tools or books.  This article on writing literate programs in R should be of some help http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/how-to-use-Org-Babel-for-R.html

Comment: I don't understand the hold either: can somebody please explain the reasoning? It seems like a perfectly valid org-mode question.

Comment: To the OP: I think the answer to your question involves tangling.See http://orgmode.org/org.html#Extracting-source-code

Comment: The objections all came from data analysts: I guess the R tag is the problem?

Comment: I don't see why this is put on hold. It is a simple quesiton - how to export R code embedded in an org file into R. It is a technical quesiton regarding org mode and not opinion based. To the OP, look at org-tangle. You put your R code in #+BEGIN_SRC/#+END_SRC and org-mode will export that to an R input file - it is a form of literate programming with org-mode

Comment: This is clearly not off-topic. I want to do something in org-mode and I don't know how to do it, so I think that's the purpose of this site. I believe none of the comments here fully answer my question. I will edit the original question and add some more information. Thanks.